# How to create 1 event handler to run different functions with 2 separate clicks (subsequently)?

Tags: jquery

/*I would like to program one event handler to run 2 different events subsequently with one function/effect running on the first click and the second function/effect to run when the mouse is clicked a second time. Right now, both functions/effects run on the first click. Thank you…*/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //box slides down on first click
  $("#firstElement").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").slideDown(1000);
  });
  //box should fade out on second(subsequent) click    
  $("#firstElement").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").fadeOut(1000);
  });


}); //endReady
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lime;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="firstElement">clickMe</p>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] please. And did you check the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Thank you, j08691-this is my first time attempting a post to this site. I made some revisions to clarify my issue. Hope it helps. Thanks again, and to anyone else who may be kind enough to reply…

Comment: You'd need to keep track of the clicks since there's nothing build-in to handle the sequence you're after. So a counter or flag of some sort. For example, a variable like `click_one` set to `false`. When the click handlers are called, if it's false, only do the slideDown and set it to true. Then have another condition, also called on every click, that checks to see if that counter is true, and if so, run the fade.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance j08691–but upon inspection i realized i had another problem altogether, so I threw it back out there. Thanks again…